# Geojson using Jackson and Java

Tags: java, jackson, geojson

Does anyone know where I can find good examples of opening a geojson file and reading it using the Jackson library?  I cannot create a class to serialize was we are dealing with several different files.

I have been searching for samples, and it seems to be non-existent with this library.  Anyone?

I am dealing with geometry with different types also; MutiPolygon, Polygon for example.

Thanks...

Comment: Well, I know I have a JSON Schema which can at least validate GeoJSON inputs... But no POJO mapping.